# handling stale caches with multiple servers

Tags: mysql, .net, caching, invalidation

We currently have a website hosted on one server, and we are looking into adding a new server.  The main issue is about caching.  Some items are cached based on when they are changed.  However right now, they are changed in the same process, hence the cache can be invalidated.

If the website is hosted on two servers, the changes can be done on both servers and they will not be notified of such changes.  The cache needs to remain as it drastically speeds up the website.  I would prefer if the cache is not taken out-of-process in a cache-server, as it slows down to the speed of network rather than memory, and adds complexity to the servers.

The website is implemented in .Net, with MySQL as it's backing datastore.   My issue is how the process can be notified when data changes.  Is it possible that MySQL will automatically notify all registered clients when any data changes?  I've used RavenDb, which has a similar feature which comes in very handy.  I couldn't find anything similar for MySQL. If this is not possible, any ideas how one would approach this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Distributed caching is a complex topic. It sounds like you are running a more basic in-memory cache. If this is the case, you will need to handle synchronisation yourself, or be happy with  "eventual consistency" of the data, assuming you have some stale key checking mechanism.

Personally I would look into using memcached (we use Couchbase). Your opinion on this becoming a network bottleneck may be unrealised, although yes in real terms memory access is faster. In practical terms, we noticed that Couchbase caching was more than fast enough, and it is atomic at the key level. It will handle key distribution over nodes.

As for MySQL pushing notifications to clients, I am not sure but I don't think so. You could emulate this yourself if you have a layer of code (DAL etc) over database access.

It is also difficult to reconcile the desire to have the cache follow the same integrity principles as the database. If you achieve this then all you have done is made an in-memory database. Caching is supposed to be a trade-off of data accuracy over time to increase scalability.

Comment: Yes, I am running a basic in-memory cache.  The problem is that this is an old codebase, and some objects in cache are not easily serializable.  Hence, in-memory works fine but out-of-process requires them to be serializable.  Couchbase seems to be a NoSQL database, not a cache server? I think for now I'll have to contend with eventual consistency.  If the database server supports change notifications, this would be a piece of cake to implement.  Unfortunately MySQL does not seem to.

Comment: @KarlCassar Couchbase is sort of an in-between. It uses memcached under the hood but offers disc backing and atomicity at the key level, so it's sort of a mild in-memory database. We tend to use the caching side of it more than the disc backing side.